# Over 750 kb/s wifi disconnects

Tags: wireless

I have wrote before  [topic](https://askubuntu.com/questions/536468/wifi-disconnects-all-the-time-and-problem-with-nautilus) but I found out a new information by testing torrent downloading, if the limit is on 750 everything is fine, but if unlimited, my download grows up to 1-2mb and dies. I changed MTU for 1500 but it didn't help, do you have any idea what could I do with it?

Edit: **You don't have to read comments, I'll make a shortcut when we'll solve it :)**
Until now: it's my cheap router's fault (belkin f7d2301 v1)

Comment: Some cheap routers don't like it, when there are many open connections.  Try once unlimited speed but reduce the number of connections for bittorrent.

Comment: I think you should have updated the old question. Now that you **have** create a new question I guess it would be okay for you if we close the old one. Right?

Comment: Can I limit amount of connection in router, or for the computer? Torrent is a minor problem. My issue is that I can't work fast, because opening 2-3 tabs which I work on + youtube and internet is dead for up to 10min.

Yes, we can close old ones. I just keep investigating it but with edits nobody looks there later.

Comment: I have never seen an option to limit the number of connections on a router. Do you have a possibility (temporarily) to switch the router?

Comment: No, but it's a laptop so I will just go with this one to my office and check the error. However how can I be sure that it's not a fault of the router there?

Comment: Either way we will gain some insight about what might be the problem. Alas, I think you won't be able to use Bittorrent at your office.

Comment: I'm downloading 28 peers, 2mb/s + youtube + 5 websites opened on fast. It's my routers fault, can I configure it somehow, or is it because it's a cheap shit I've got for free? it's belkin f7d2301 v1

Comment: The first thing I would try is to upgrade the routers firmware. Alternatively you might want to try to install an alternative OS on it like dd-wrt. But be careful, you can turn your router unusable like this. Check here this link if to see if your router is supported: http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Supported_Devices

Comment: Mine is not listed in this link. I updated the router and played with security settings, but non of these helped. What can be my other step?

Comment: Apparently dd-wrt doens't support your router. About upgrading your router, Google came up with that: http://www.belkin.com/us/support-article?articleNum=10797

Comment: of course I already did it, however "upgrade" was to 1.0v so nothing changed.

Comment: Then I'm all out of options... I'd buy another router in your situation.

Comment: Dare I invite you to [accept an answer](http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers)?

Answer (score 2):

## It could be a router problem

Try to connect with a different router. Maybe you can test with one at your office? If it works Ubuntu isn't at fault. Now you have the following options with your router:

- Try upgrading your router firmware
- You might want to check if you can install an alternative OS on your router, like dd-wrt. Check this [page](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Supported_Devices) to see if it does.

  Just be careful: Errors while changing your firmware can make your router unresponsive (also known as *bricking*).
- If all else fails, maybe it's time to buy a better router.

Answer (score -1):

I have solved the same kind of issue like this:

I limit the number of peer connections to about 10 - 20 and now it works fine.